# Not Displaying Data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oop, collections

Can any one please help me for this.

```
public Dictionary<string,object> UserExistOrNot()
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> result = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conStr"].ConnectionString);
            string _userName = "user01";
            string _password = "user";
            string sqlQuery = "select * from [User] t0 inner join UserProfile t1 on t0.UserId=t1.UserId where t0.UserName='" + _userName + "' and t0.Password='" + _password+"'";
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlQuery, con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "usertable");
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    result.Add("UserId", dr["UserId"]);
                    result.Add("UserName", dr["UserName"]);
                    result.Add("Password", dr["Password"]);
                    result.Add("Email", dr["Email"]);
                    result.Add("Mobile", dr["Mobile"]);
                    result.Add("Gender", dr["Gender"]);
                    result.Add("Street1", dr["Street1"]);
                    result.Add("Street2", dr["Street2"]);
                    result.Add("Street3", dr["Street3"]);
                    result.Add("Street4", dr["Street4"]);
                    result.Add("CityId", dr["CityId"]);
                    result.Add("StateId", dr["StateId"]);
                    result.Add("Country", dr["Country"]);
                }
            }
            else
                return result;

        return result;
    }
```

Output displaying like this:

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]
```

I want to display the data instead of type

Comment: where you use this result, show that code, your binding is wrong

Comment: Output where? In a view?

Comment: @SandipPatel actually this UserExistornot is a method calling from an action method of my controller. So for test purpose i want to display the data on browser before calling the method from my action method

Comment: @StephenMuecke in a browser

Comment: You have shown a whole lot of code irrelevant to the question but omitted the relevant bit  your view code and the controller method that displays it!

Answer (score 0):

Browser understands pure text, xml or html, but not complex types, so you have to return one of those types, or create a view with model Dictionary and iterate throw keys and vslues to see it.